# Как запускать программу без sudo в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Зашел в файл:

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

Внес изменения:

```
MY_USER ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/unoconv, /usr/bin/loimpress
```

Сохранил, перезашёл в учетку, но все равно команду конвертации не запускается без **sudo**:

```
/usr/bin/loimpress loimpress --convert-to pdf --outdir /home/MY_PATH_TOFOLDER/ /home/MY_PATH_TOFOLDER/test.pptx
```

Выходит сообщение:

> Warning: failed to read path from javaldx

Comment: У вас в вопросе какая-то непоследовательная логика: вы хотите запустить программу без sudo, но при этом почему-то редактируете конфиг программы sudo. Вполне логично предположить, что для использования конфига программы sudo нужно запускать программу sudo ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А ещё в моей убунте такой ошибки нет — это намекает на то, что вы, вероятно, каким-то образом сломали свою систему (но каким именно — у меня идей нет)

Comment: (...хотя учитывая, что этот вопрос был задан раньше чем [тот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515517) — возможно, это всё уже неактуально, хех мда)

Comment: обычно сам ненужный запуск с sudo и ломает что-то, типа меняет владельца конфигов на root

Answer (score 1):

Вы запускаете не от имени суперпользователя (без `sudo`). Опция `ALL=NOPASSWD` позволяет запускать без пароля, а не вообще всем, т.к. исполняемый файл, очевидно, либо принадлежит `root`, либо использует права суперпользователя для своей корректной работы.

Если вам претит конкретно писать `sudo`, то можете написать *alias* на команду (только для текущей сессии терминала):

```bash
$ alias loimpress_cmd="sudo /usr/bin/loimpress"
```

Файл `/etc/sudoers` безопасно редактировать только через `visudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема не в правах sudo, а настройках java или переменных среды в запускающей сессии. Проверьте `java --version`. Посмотрите, может надо поставить пакет поддержки `libreoffice-java-common`